# Raphael.js alternatives of deprecated functions and responsive function

Tags: javascript, raphael

I've created an interactive map as geo chart to gather info such as number of purchases from each state.

It has used with Raphael.js 1.5.2, there are 2 problems when I try to update new version of Raphael.js as 2.1.2, the current documentation of Raphael didn't help me.

1)  It throws some errors in console:

```
Paper.safari is not a function

Paper.popup is not a function
```

What are alternatives of these functions?

2) The display viewport is 700 x 500, when I try to resize window as mobile version, isn't responsive, how to make it responsive?

Thanks!

Comment: What are these functions doing?

Comment: According to old documentation:

paper.safari is a workaround function to fix render bug in Safari

paper.popup is a tooltip function when you use mouse hover the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example only svg and js..

https://jsfiddle.net/9u9ueLes

```
document.getElementById().style.fill = "#f00"
```

Comment: Is possible to port this currently interactive map in following gif:

http://i.imgur.com/agYGGGA.gif

and is responsive?

Comment: look here, you can do it with out raphael/mapael just plain svg and some javascript.. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Mexico_Map.svg

Comment: Funny, I have to rewrite each path as state to make tooltip, however, thanks for your answer, I will adopt Mapael.

Comment: @Ivan oh, right you would have to create some kind of pathId > tooltip mapping to make it programmatically.. However, hope you will get it to work, somehow ;)

Comment: nice! actually I wonder how to convert this into .JS map data such like this http://jsfiddle.net/neveldo/TUYHN/ as http://www.vincentbroute.fr//mapael/source/js/maps/france_departments.js

Comment: @Ivan Do you see the 'd' attribute in the 'path' tag of the svg? this is the department-xx string for your js object.. the best would be first extract the data into a json, and then just use it..